# What is wrong with this JSON string? Also it work with JSONLint

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

This JSON string appears to be invalid but when I check it with JSONLint it says it's valid so where is the problem. Error pops up at position 252.

```
let test = JSON.parse('[{"id":6,"item_type":"cybro_unit","unitId":6,"pos_id":9,"name":"CyBro-2","image":"images/cybro/defaultBro.png","layer":"10","positionX":111.0,"positionY":249.0,"layerName":"10","sizeX":201.0,"sizeY":168.0,"z_index":9999,"showLabel":true,"hint":"CyBro-2\nPovezan: true\nVelikost X: 201.523163\nVelikost Y: 168.675491","enabled":true,"connected":false}]');

[{
    "id": 6,
    "item_type": "cybro_unit",
    "unitId": 6,
    "pos_id": 9,
    "name": "CyBro-2",
    "image": "images/cybro/defaultBro.png",
    "layer": "10",
    "positionX": 111.0,
    "positionY": 249.0,
    "layerName": "10",
    "sizeX": 201.0,
    "sizeY": 168.0,
    "z_index": 9999,
    "showLabel": true,
    "hint": "CyBro-2\nPovezan: true\nVelikost X: 201.523163\nVelikost Y: 168.675491", // here at CyBro-2
    "enabled": true,
    "connected": false
}]
```

Comment: I just added the comment to let users know where the error occurs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its most likely that escape character man, have you tried escaping the \ so whatever you are doing does not detect it as a line break?

EDIT:

i mean i just did it and it worked, try this:

```
JSON.parse('[{"id":6,"item_type":"cybro_unit","unitId":6,"pos_id":9,"name":"CyBro-2","image":"images/cybro/defaultBro.png","layer":"10","positionX":111.0,"positionY":249.0,"layerName":"10","sizeX":201.0,"sizeY":168.0,"z_index":9999,"showLabel":true,"hint":"CyBro-2\\nPovezan: true\\nVelikost X: 201.523163\\nVelikost Y: 168.675491","enabled":true,"connected":false}]');
```

Comment: I will try it with \r before \n and it will probably work i'm just confused because it works on my other subpage.

Answer (score 2):

The string you are passing to `JSON.parse` has a few *literal newline* characters in it:

```
"hint":"CyBro-2\nPovezan: true\nVelikost X: 201.523163\nVelikost Y: 168.675491"
               ^^             ^^                      ^^
```

```js
const str = '[{"id":6,"item_type":"cybro_unit","unitId":6,"pos_id":9,"name":"CyBro-2","image":"images/cybro/defaultBro.png","layer":"10","positionX":111.0,"positionY":249.0,"layerName":"10","sizeX":201.0,"sizeY":168.0,"z_index":9999,"showLabel":true,"hint":"CyBro-2\nPovezan: true\nVelikost X: 201.523163\nVelikost Y: 168.675491","enabled":true,"connected":false}]';
console.log(str);
```

Newline characters are not valid in JSON - instead, you should have a literal `\` followed by a literal `n` to indicate that the parsed string in the object should contain a literal newline. You can do this by double-escaping the `\`s to indicate a single literal `\`, eg:

```
"hint":"CyBro-2\\nPovezan: true\\nVelikost X: 201.523163\\nVelikost Y: 168.675491"
```

```js
let test = JSON.parse(
'[{"id":6,"item_type":"cybro_unit","unitId":6,"pos_id":9,"name":"CyBro-2","image":"images/cybro/defaultBro.png","layer":"10","positionX":111.0,"positionY":249.0,"layerName":"10","sizeX":201.0,"sizeY":168.0,"z_index":9999,"showLabel":true,"hint":"CyBro-2\\nPovezan: true\\nVelikost X: 201.523163\\nVelikost Y: 168.675491","enabled":true,"connected":false}]'
);

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not escaped your newline character `\n`:

```js
let test = JSON.parse('[{"id":6,"item_type":"cybro_unit","unitId":6,"pos_id":9,"name":"CyBro-2","image":"images/cybro/defaultBro.png","layer":"10","positionX":111.0,"positionY":249.0,"layerName":"10","sizeX":201.0,"sizeY":168.0,"z_index":9999,"showLabel":true,"hint":"CyBro-2\\nPovezan: true\\nVelikost X: 201.523163\\nVelikost Y: 168.675491","enabled":true,"connected":false}]');
console.log(test);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You can also do this by replacing all `\n` with `\\n`:

```js
let test = '[{"id":6,"item_type":"cybro_unit","unitId":6,"pos_id":9,"name":"CyBro-2","image":"images/cybro/defaultBro.png","layer":"10","positionX":111.0,"positionY":249.0,"layerName":"10","sizeX":201.0,"sizeY":168.0,"z_index":9999,"showLabel":true,"hint":"CyBro-2\\nPovezan: true\\nVelikost X: 201.523163\\nVelikost Y: 168.675491","enabled":true,"connected":false}]';
test = test.replace(/\n/g, "\\n");
console.log(JSON.parse(test));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```